# Sending Screenshots using NetComm dll to Host

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, client-server

I am using NetComm dll to handle multiuser. My problem is when i send text it works fine but when i take screenshots its not working.
    My client code is

```
ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmpScreenshot.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] buffer;
            buffer  =imageToByteArray(bmpScreenshot);
            client.SendData(buffer);
```

And the function that converts image to byte array is:

```
 public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

And on the receiving end i handled like this:

```
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Data); // Data is byte array 
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

After recieve i shows image in the picture box.

Using NetComm dll i can only send and receive data in bytearray format.

NetComm dll provide me the facility to communicate from a client to another client by using its id. When Server starts it waits for the client and once client get connected it start giving them id in some manner like abc1, abc2, abc3.  and When abc1 wants to communicate to abc3 it simply enters abc3 as an id instead of IP and send message that message should be deliverd to the abc3. 
[image: This is server]

[image: This is client]

As you can see there are two clients connected to the server and both get the id like jack1 and jack2. now if they want to communicate with each other they simply type there respective ids and send the message.

Comment: or any suggestion for client to client communication, i mean when a client want to send a personal message to other client what approach i try?

Comment: In what sense does it not working?

Comment: This question is lacking so much detail... You really need to provide more information, such as an [mcve] of how you're using NetComm so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to use a tcp server having multiple clients, and all the clients can communicate each other by providing a client id.

Comment: May be there are any other way to achieve this, or i am doing it wrong. Because when i send a picture from a client i want that it would appear to any other client but its not happening. In case of text its working fine.

Comment: i added a textbox in client and in the senddata() pass that id to which client you want to send the message, if you dont define anything by default it goes to server.

Comment: Okay What Approach i try to send a msg to other client from a client  connected to the same tcp server.

Comment: @AnoopMishra have You checked my answer? Can You specify more the problem?

Comment: yes i checked it but the problem is same.

Comment: @AnoopMishra one of the possible explanation could be because the image data stream is not sent completely. To test this, try your procedure without sending the stream to TCP client first. Do the image-byte array conversion locally first. See if it works. if it does, we know that the problem lies with the incomplete bytes retrieved, not with any of the logic. Have you tried your method locally first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to make a simple client -> client message sending, that will be a bitmap. I had problem when I tried to use it with different port, but the port was blocked, and that was the problem. Check that as well. Check the code, and see if it helps:

```
namespace CommTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        NetComm.Host host = new NetComm.Host(10010);
        NetComm.Client client1 = new NetComm.Client();
        NetComm.Client client2 = new NetComm.Client();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            host.StartConnection();
            client1.Connect("localhost", 10010, "Jack");
            client2.Connect("localhost", 10010, "Jack2");
            client2.DataReceived += client2_DataReceived;
            client1.SendData(imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile("Bitmap1.bmp")), "Jack2");
        }

        void client2_DataReceived(byte[] Data, string ID)
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Data); // Data is byte array 
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            // pictureBox1.Refresh(); works without it
        }

        public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            host.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also i can't able to implement two clients from the server.  i mean do i have to write two different client programs. please i need explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A full server / client implementation may be like this. You don't need to implement 2 different client programs, but client and server should be different. It's an example how to use broadcast>

Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] argv)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        // if You run the program like "CommTest.exe 10010", than it will be host.
        // if You run it like "CommTest.exe localhost 10010", than it will be client connecting to localhost.
        if (argv.Length == 1)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form2(new Host(int.Parse(argv[0]))));
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1(new Client(argv[0], int.Parse(argv[1]))));
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(NetComm.Client client)
    {
        _client = client;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // there is a button to broadcast picture on the client.
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // update the image that should be broadcasted as You like.
        _client.SendData(imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile("Bitmap1.bmp")));
    }

    NetComm.Client _client;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        _client.DataReceived += client_DataReceived;
    }

    void client_DataReceived(byte[] Data, string ID)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Data); // Data is byte array 
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    }

    public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        _client.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Client.cs

```
class Client: NetComm.Client
{
    public Client(string ip, int port):base()
    {
        // in this example, the ids are not considered. In a real world situation Clients should send a first message to the host,
        // and host should reply with a free id. That id should be in the place of Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        Connect(ip, port, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(NetComm.Host host)
    {
        _host = host;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    NetComm.Host _host;

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Click += Button1_Click;
    }

    // there is a button to close the connection on the host form.
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _host.CloseConnection();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        _host.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Host.cs

```
class Host: NetComm.Host
{
    public Host(int port):base(port)
    {
        StartConnection();
        DataReceived += Host_DataReceived;
    }

    void Host_DataReceived(string ID, byte[] Data)
    {
        Brodcast(Data);
    }
}
```